# How can I program a STM32 Nucleo board without using the on-board ST-LINK?

Tags: stm32, st-link

I don't have any prehistoric mini-USB cable and nor can I find one in nearby stores. The board doesn't come with one either. Can I still use my Nucleo board? How?

I should add that I have a STLink V2 programmer. Can I use that to directly program the Nucleo board?

Edit: It worked using the answer below. I'm adding this in case anyone else tries to do this: it works for me ONLY when I connect BOTH the 3.3V and 5V properly. Otherwise, the GPIO logic levels are messed up and no peripherals work. Sometimes the board itself refuses to be programmed as well.

Comment: There might be a better way using the Nucleo development tools, but this video shows how to upload a hex file to a generic STM32 mcu using SWD and a STLink programmer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KgR3uM21y7o

Comment: cut a usb cable and solder the wires. surely a mini-usb is not that hard to come by?

Comment: @Kartman it is here. I used to have those Chinese handheld mp3/ mp4 players back in 2010-2013 and they had mini USB. But here they have been COMPLETELY phased out for the more available micro USB. Unfortunately, I can't find any of the old ones I had, probably thrown them out. I have like 15-20 micro USBs though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use an external programmer. First, remove both of the ST-Link jumpers from your Nucleo board to cut the on-board ST-Link from the main microcontroller.

You need these connections for SWD interface:

1. Power: You need to power the Nucleo board somehow. One can use 5V or 3V3 pins to provide external power. I'm not sure if your ST-Link can provide power. Chinese clones can do that, but the original one may not. The original ST-Link may also require a 3V3 connection to detect the presence of power at target, even though it doesn't use that pin to provide power to the target.
2. GND
3. SWDIO: Probably needs to be connected to PA13. Check the datasheet or CubeMX
4. SWCLK: Probably needs to be connected to PA14. Check the datasheet or CubeMX
5. nRST: This is optional and depends on tool settings.

But I would prefer obtaining a proper USB A - Mini B cable.

Comment: Do I use the SWD pins on the programmer part of the nucleo board?

Comment: No, they are connected to the on-board ST-Link. You need them when you use the on-board ST-Link to program some other external uC. As you don't have access to the on-board ST-Link, they have no use in your situation.

Comment: Ok. I'll try to find them on the board. I still don't understand why they use mini usb, and then not provide one as they are pretty outdated.

Comment: I can confirm it is working with PA_13 and PA_14 as labelled in https://os.mbed.com/media/uploads/adustm/nucleo_f446re_morpho_left_2016_7_22.png as SWDIO and SWCLK respectively. And @Tagli, thanks much for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

With the standard STLink probe, use this:
[image]