# STM32CubeProgrammer Error: No STM32 target found!

Tags: stm32, st-link

I have a nucleo board but no mini-USB B so I hooked it up to an external STLink V2 programmer([related post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/566511/how-can-i-program-a-stm32-nucleo-board-without-using-the-on-board-st-link)).

The problems:

1. At first it was working as expected but after a while STM32CubeProgrammer gives an error while trying to connect:[image]
2. It works 1 out of ~20 tries, sometimes even more. When it works, it works fine. But the problem with plugging in again and again is, my laptop's USB port is becoming loose. I can already tell one of them is pretty loose already.
3. I also tried holding the reset button and then trying to connect it, but same result(I have the reset pin connected, I don't think I needed to do that manually).
4. I tried different modes, frequencies etc., to no avail.

What can cause this and how can I go about fixing it?

Comment: Have you tried changing your USB data cable?

Comment: @dharmik There's no data cable. The STLink programmer connects directly to the female USB port.

Comment: Upgrade the St link firmware and USB drivers

Comment: @Sorenp I tried that already, didn't work. The actual problem turned out to be loose jumper wires. The STLink-jumper wire solution seems to be very finicky. I wish there was a big connector that attaches to the STLink end, that's always the problem. I have to hold the jumper wires firmly on the STLink and then it connects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had solved the problem within a few days of posting this question (before the very expensive usb cable I ordered online arrived) by shortening the jumper wires and soldering the ends of the wires to the connectors.

It seems that the cube programmer (and also the mbed studio I tried later on with bluepill and blackpill boards) fails to connect to the board using STLink devices if the jumper wires are even a tiny bit loose or are lengthy.

I know that the programming is probably done via UART and the corresponding UART baud rate doesn't seem to be too much for regular jumper wires to fail, still I have no idea why it doesn't work.

I would also like to add that I have used SPI and UART protocol faster than the mentioned baud rate reliably with the same jumper wires and a breadboard. It seems to be a STLink only issue.

Answer (score 1):

Change "Reset mode" in *STM32CubeProgrammer* to different modes like:

[image]

I was getting the same error and I changed 'hardware reset' to 'software reset' and create "new project".

..my problem was solved

Comment: I had already tried that. Worked intermittently. The problem turned out to be the jumper wires. Using shorter wires and soldering them on both ends solved the problem permanently.